# Linking in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2015

So I'm trying to link a library into my project, but I'm not getting the option to link after clicking on add existing item and selecting the .lib to add...
when I click on the arrow near the add tab, I just get the options "add" and "show previous versions" ...
so how do I actually link in visual studio 2015 ?

Comment: Do you have any (vague) idea about all the _VStudio_ settings?  Link the lib in and you should be  OK.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries aren't treated like source files. Remove the library from the source files list, and instead right-click on a project in Solution Explorer, select Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input and add libraries to the `Additional Dependencies` list. Suppose you want to add foo.lib, the line would look like

```
foo.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

This can all be found in the [linker documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx)

Comment: Alternatively, do it right from the source code, using `#pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib");` (see [comment (C/C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

If your project is C++, try this:

1. Open project property window
2. Go to `Configuration Properties->Linker->Input`, add your lib to `Additional Dependencies`
3. Go to `Configuration Properties->Linker->General`, add directory of your lib to `Additional Library Directories`

Comment: thanks, that was perfect, working... but strange thing is , using codeblocks and mingw this problem of linking does not arise, but with visual studio yes, I was thinking visual studio since it is a windows property should already contain all the .lib before hand...instead of me having to manually do this linking...

Comment: and I also just noted that visual studio 2015 on disk is taking a whooping 2,74 gigabyte..so what the hell does it contains then? lol... or what don't I still understand?

Comment: It takes two steps to work for lib files. `1.` The lib file exists. `2.` The path to lib configured. So that compiler can file lib. I think CodeBlocks or MinGW does that. For another question, besides IDE itself, VS contains `Windows Kits` and `Microsoft Foundation Classes (Known as MFC)` and lots of libraries. It also supports `C#`, `JavaScript` and other languages.

Comment: @user3374754: It is the developer's job to feed the correct parameters to the tools. The IDE cannot (and should not) guess this, and implement fixups. Visual Studio does link against certain libraries (e.g. kernel32.lib) when creating a standard project. You might want to consider compiling on the command line until you understand the build process, before moving back to the IDE. Apart from that, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).